# How to add units of measurement inside input field in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, input

I have an input field and I want the units of measurement inside the input field. I am getting this

[image: here is the wrong output]

instead of this
[image: here is the right output]

here is the code

```
<div className={classes.Shopping__count}>
    <input type="number" value={itemCount} step={props.count} onChange={itemCountHandler} className={classes.Shopping__count} />
    <span>{props.unit}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add some CSS to the span. e.g.

```
span.shift-left {
    left: -4em;
}
```